# Can I replicate this equation in excel through subqueries? I started differentiating between purchases and sales but now I'm stuck

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-workbench, equation

just started learning sql last week and am trying to use a table imported using .csv to then carry out functions and add columns in the final table that perform these equations.

I am tasked with the first equation which is Taking the ((Purchases - Shares)/ (Purchases + sales), for a given owner, for a given year.

I have started a query that asks to look at transcode column and identify if it is P for Purchase, S for Sale and then from there I want to look at the shares column to then take that amount and plug it into the equation.

I am unsure if what I am trying to do is feasible?

Should I break it down further into seperate tables for purchases and shares?

Thank you.

[Picture of My data table labeled IHD in MySQL workebnch]
[image: 1]




[MySQL Workbench to give you idea of code I wrote to distinguish Sales from purchases]
[image: 2]

Comment: What you are trying to do is exactly what sql was created to do, i am not sure about the data but is see it working making use of grouping and filtering statements.

Comment: Do you think the first query I have in myworkbench is what I need first to then group and filtering? I am very new to SQL and this project is very demanding as a finance background rather than CS

Comment: You should provide the columns for that do you have sale and purchase as two columns in the DB? If that is so you don't need transcode filter. Further, i see a lot of duplicate rows in the excel you attached you should find a way group sales and purchase by owner_name and year. And then user the formula

Comment: No I do not because each row is a seperate sale or a purchase; I am hoping to trancode filter so that I can deduce the # number of shares to place into the equation ((P - S)/ (P+S) per owner per year. The information is not duplicated, thank you for asking me to check!

Comment: You can try something like select sum(shares) as num_of_shares , transcode, owner, year from table group by owner, transcode, YEAR(year) this should give you details of number of shares for sales and purchase per owner per year.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
select sum(shares) as num_of_shares , transcode, owner, YEAR(year) from table group by owner, transcode, YEAR(year)
```

This should give you aggregate of number of shares for sales and purchase per owner per year. After you can plug in this information into other queries to get the desired result.